Understanding the Properties and Applications of My Custom Kernel Function
I am a hobbyist and I have made this kernel that I want to use for varies things. Can you please help me understand the proprieties of what I have created and how I can possibly integrate it correctly so I can use it as a pdf? As far as I know, the limit at x = d for this function is just $b \cdot c$. I plan on using it as a kernel for a low pass filter as well and I want to understand the frequency cut off. It would also be great if some one can point me in the right direction to understand how to use this in the frequency domain.
The parameters for this function are: A controls the width, B controls the peek, C controls the tail, and D controls the mean.
Desmos plot for the function
Another perspective on the function
$$\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{2b(x - d)}{a}\right) \cdot \operatorname{csch}\left(\frac{2(x - d)}{a c}\right)$$

Your questions are too vague. What do you want to compute concretely ?

Also, the parameters $a$ and $c$ are redundant. Indeed, $c$ may be absorbed by $a$ and $b$ through rescaling, i.e. by setting $a' = ac$ and $b' = bc$.

@Abezhiko Interesting, Im not sure I follow on how to absorb c? I want to use this as a pdf and as a kernel for a low pass filter. For a pdf I need to figure out how to integrate it and for the low pass filter I need to figure out hot to determine the frequency response.

If I were you, since this function possesses a unique simple pole at the origin, I would integrate it with the help of the residue formula.

@Abezhiko Thats super interesting!! I will see if I can learn how to do that! :D
